# How to wrap mean and CI plot in function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, functional-programming

I have the dataset below produced by `summarySE` which shows the mean and confidence interval across groups of `t` and `sex`.

```
mn.bmd <- structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                     2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", "male"), class = "factor"), 
                   t = c(10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L), 
                   N = c(2731L, 2750L, 2607L, 2524L, 2397L, 2427L, 2452L, 2374L, 
                         2343L, 1935L), bmd = c(0.771745743658987, 0.852563274643638, 
                                                0.959264663475704, 1.00448137517321, 1.03961818701633, 0.78197475849084, 
                                                0.84601311310275, 0.953283665154095, 1.0561553454168, 1.14395286996851
                         ), sd = c(0.0546859583968217, 0.0728002055433497, 0.0765731777406101, 
                                   0.0729628520321917, 0.0752411677480204, 0.0524685598606996, 
                                   0.060935438701901, 0.085630182993752, 0.0964219075622181, 
                                   0.100009937518834), se = c(0.00104644155540708, 0.00138824544949947, 
                                                              0.00149970608925882, 0.00145230263867668, 0.00153681471482534, 
                                                              0.00106503592133958, 0.00123057959424098, 0.00175746431217515, 
                                                              0.00199200110406779, 0.00227354037595468), ci = c(0.00205189747680689, 
                                                                                                                0.00272210959875271, 0.00294073574524029, 0.00284782704999121, 
                                                                                                                0.00301362384271727, 0.00208847400752308, 0.00241308331525491, 
                                                                                                                0.0034463245617893, 0.003906269195061, 0.00445884772686761
                                                              )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                                                                                      "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), .Names = c("sex", "t", "N", "bmd", 
                                                                                                                                                 "sd", "se", "ci"))
```

I can plot the mean and confidence intervals by groups of `t` using the code below:

```
ggplot(mn.bmd, aes(x=t, y=bmd, colour=sex)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=bmd-ci, ymax=bmd+ci), size=0.3, width=.3) + 
geom_line() + geom_point(size=3, shape=21)
```

i would like to wrap this ggplot code in a function in order to repeat it for different dataframes (that all have the same structure but with different column names for `y`) - I have tried using `aes_string` but no luck?

```
my_plot <- function(df, y) {
ggplot(df, aes_string(x="t", y=y, colour="sex")) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci), size=0.3, width=.3) + 
geom_line() + 
geom_point(size=3, shape=21)
}

#Error message
Error in y - ci : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: Why `bmdlh` for `geom_errorbar` but not `bmd`?

Comment: Sorry that was an error in copying code here - i was just changing column names - but this is not related to the issue I am having

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal dataset with `dput` output and evaluate your question a little more? All data frames will have the same structure, right?

Comment: Thanks - I provided the dput output and clarified that all dataframes will have same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if all data frames are formed in the same way:

```
library(dplyr)

my_plot <- function(df, y) {
  ymin <- df[[y]] - df$ci
  ymax <- df[[y]] + df$ci
  ggplot(df, aes_string(x="t", y=y, colour="sex")) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), size=0.3, width=.3) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(size=3, shape=21)
}

# you can replace mn.bmd with other data frames and check the result
my_plot(df = mn.bmd, y = "bmd")
```

Comment: Thanks - the different data frames have different names for y (how would you edit your code to allow for this?)

Comment: Thanks for this but still having a problem regarding the ymax and ymin - these should be 'ymin=y-ci, ymax=y+ci' This is because the y column will vary. However, when i make this edit - the following error occurs: 'Error in y - ci : non-numeric argument to binary operator'

Comment: @aelhak; I forgot to tweak that part. Check this out.

Answer (score 1):

I think that just wrapping the ggplot call in a function should work, as long as all dataframes have the same column names.

If your dataframes do not have the same colnames then you have to pass the colname to `ggplot()` as a string with the `get()` function. So for example instead of

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=t))
```

you would have

```
ggplot(x,aes(x=get(colname_x)))
```

where `colname_x` is a string containing the name of the column that you want to pass to `ggplot()` as `x`

**edit**

In response to the OP's comment:
I would add the name of the column to the function's argument and add a get() statement in the call to ggplot(), like so

```
my_plot <- function(df,colname_y) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x=t, y=get(colname_y), colour=sex)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=bmd-ci, ymax=bmd+ci), size=0.3, width=.3) +
  geom_line() + geom_point(size=3, shape=21)
}
```

Comment: Thanks - so could you please clarify how you might edit the code below to work for dataframes that have different column names for y?                                          
  'my_plot <- function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x=t, y=bmd, colour=sex)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=bmd-ci, ymax=bmd+ci), size=0.3, width=.3) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point(size=3, shape=21)
}'

Comment: No problem! I edited my answer to answer your question